# How to load array of object into extjs gridpanel

Tags: arrays, object, extjs

I am new to ExtJS. In examples, I do not find any one similar to my situation: I have an Array of Object like bellow:
        arr = new Array();
        obj = new Object();
        obj.StringField = "Field1";
        obj.IntField = 1;
        arr.push(obj);
        obj = new Object();
        obj.StringField = "Field2";
        obj.IntField = 3;
        arr.push(obj);
        obj = new Object();
        obj.StringField = "Field3";
        obj.IntField = 5;
        arr.push(obj);
How to put this in to GridPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a grid panel with an ArrayReader : http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual:Data:Readers:ArrayReader

There's also an example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext/examples/grid/array-grid.html

Comment: links not accessible anymore .. @bogdan do you latest links for this